# How many seconds should I set for timeout when my iOS app is querying a server for messages?

Tags: ios, timeout, request, seconds

Currently I have a timeout of 90 seconds. If I encounter an error where a user hits refresh and it cannot find a connection, it will keep checking for 90 seconds displaying a "Refreshing" label on the screen.

How many seconds is the best practice? I am worried if I go too low then it will always timeout and not poll in new messages.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check for the network availability using Reachability APIs the you should go for requesting to server. If network is not connected then there is no point for going to request to server.

And ideal timeout time is 30 seconds for any server request call.